# the number of items sold for a specific material on the first occurrence

Tags: sql

items sold for a specific material on the first occurrence

```
items_id|number of items
452202000|3
452202000|5
452202000|5
```

Comment: First, according to what? Does the table also have a date or sequence column?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you could add at least another items_id. And specify the expected result.

Comment: And please mention your dbms with version.

Answer (score 1):

Please mention if there is date column or incremental id to determine which transaction has been occurred first. Because without that you can't ensure correct result or even same result every time.

Here goes your query.

```
 select items_id, number_of_items 
from
(
  select items_id, number_of_items, row_number()over(partition by items_id order by (select null)) rn from yourtable
)t where rn=1
```

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table yourtable (items_id int, number_of_items int);
 insert into yourtable values(452202000,3);
 insert into yourtable values(452202000,5);
 insert into yourtable values(452202000,5);
 insert into yourtable values(452202001,2);
 insert into yourtable values(452202001,8);
```

Select query:

```
select * from yourtable
```

Sample data:

| items_id | number_of_items |
| --- | --- |
| 452202000 | 3 |
| 452202000 | 5 |
| 452202000 | 5 |
| 452202001 | 2 |
| 452202001 | 8 |

Query:

```
 select items_id, number_of_items 
 from
 (
   select items_id, number_of_items, row_number()over(partition by items_id order by (select null)) rn from yourtable
 )t where rn=1
```

Output:

| items_id | number_of_items |
| --- | --- |
| 452202000 | 3 |
| 452202001 | 2 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6fca3b920f1d89758ec90cc596064db0)*